# Where to find wordlists with gender and plural for German?

Tags: nlp, linguistics, corpus

I'm trying to write a simple text mining application to try to tell a German word's gender and plural form.

So, first of all, I need a big wordlist for training. I've searched around but could not find any list having either gender nor plural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use data from the [Durm German Lemmatizer](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/durm-german-lemmatizer), the [Morphisto Lexikon](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/lexik/TextGrid/morphisto.html), or the [ispell dictionary for German](http://www.j3e.de/ispell/igerman98/). You might find some other resources by looking at me [del.ico.us page with tag "german"](http://www.delicious.com/hmuelner/german)

Comment: The Lemmatizer seems too much for what I want, while Morphisto Lexikon had an XML I could use. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could mine the data available in the [English](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page) and [German](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aHauptseite) Wiktionaries. You can download the current data of each [here](http://download.wikipedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2) and [here](http://download.wikipedia.org/dewiktionary/latest/dewiktionary-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2).

But I warn you, [wikitext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup) is quite a fuzzy format and the English and German Wiktionary users came up with quite different ways to employ it for each project.

Comment: I didn't know those. While being great, they are waaaay too much for what I want, it's not even worth to try converting the files.